# Delete records from Oracle in sets

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-function

I am facing issue deleting set of records from a table named links_data because of huge set of data to be deleted and the Oracle DB ran out of temp space.

For the same with little knowledge of mine on Stored Procedure I wrote the below code. 
But the Stored Procedure looks to be running slow as well.

The scenario is that I need to delete the rows from links_data table where the nm_folder column in links_data table has foreign key relation with link_folders table.  nm_folder in link_folders table is the primary key and I intend to delete 10000 records at a time and commit and then again delete 10000 records and commit.

Kindly anyone please help me optimize this query. Thanks & Regards,

```
Declare

Type ty_link_floder is table of number;

tble_id_folder ty_link_floder;

    Cursor c_data is
    select id_folder from link_folders where nm_folder='User Hotlist';

    Begin
    OPEN c_data;

      LOOP
        FETCH c_data
        BULK COLLECT INTO tble_id_folder LIMIT 10000;
        EXIT WHEN tble_id_folder.count = 0;
                    FORALL i IN tble_id_folder.first .. tble_id_folder.last
        DELETE FROM links_data
        WHERE id_folder = tble_id_folder(i);
        COMMIT;

        -- Process contents of collection here.

        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(tble_id_folder.count || ' rows deleted from links_data table so far');
        tble_id_folder.delete;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE c_data;
    Exception
     When others Then
      Commit;
      Raise;
    End;
```

Comment: Are the deletes slow or is selecting from link_folders slow?
How slow is slow? 
Are there cascading deletes, delete triggers firing etc.? Available indexes on links_data.id_folder and link_folders.nm_folder?

Comment: It seems you are deleting all rows in links_data that are related to the 'User Hotlist' folders, have I understood your code rigth?

Comment: Can you provide the execution plan of the delete?

Comment: how many rows are in the link_data, how many rows with id_folder of type 'User Hotlist' exists in link_data?

Comment: "huge set of data" means absolutely nothing without context. How many rows in total are being deleted and what is the average row size in the table? How big is your temp tablespace in comparison? Have you any sort of clustering in effect (ie is the table an IOT or clustered)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try it first in one SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM links_data d
 WHERE id_folder IN (
       SELECT id_folder FROM links_folder WHERE nm_folder='User Hotlist');
```

If you run out of temp space and the DBAs cannot set up additional temp space, the best way is to recreate the table without the rows that should be deleted:

```
CREATE TABLE links_data_tmp AS
SELECT * FROM links_data d
 WHERE id_folder NOT IN (
       SELECT id_folder FROM links_folder WHERE nm_folder='User Hotlist');
```

After that, you need to rebuild all indexes and constraints on `links_data_tmp` that have been defined on `links_data`. Then you can swap the temporary table with the real one:

```
RENAME links_data TO links_data_old;
RENAME links_data_tmp TO links_data;
```

Don't forget to reapply all the privileges, too.

Answer (score 0):

You should have an index on `links_data(id_folder)` and also on the foreign key column on table `link_folders`.

But if the amount of data to be cleaned is very big(more than 30% for example) and the delete is not a continuos process, you would better make a maintenance -> recreate the tables with needed data. Insert is n times faster than delete.

Comment: :Can Limit 10000 be the problem ?

Comment: no. The problem can be the pl/sql procedure itself. it is better to delete in one statement, but the user said it fails to delete in one shot.

Comment: @GauravSoni thinking a bit, if there are only few over 10000 id_folders then the procedure makes almost the same work as single statment in the first step of loop :)